# Admob allowed period

Tags: android, admob

I'm developing application for android, and I want to show several banners to my users. Now, I'm calling `mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());` every 30 seconds.

I want to know, is it allowed by AdMob, and is this effective?

Comment: I don't think it is effective based on my experience with admob. But some one who has long experience with admob may answer your question well. what I do is I call for a new ad when ever you app comes to foreground (when onResume() is called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Load the ad once, You can change the settings of refresh rate of ads in your app setting on admob website (GoTo Manage settings and then click edit on the top just right to your app name). It will load your ad after seconds you specified . Refresh rate is between 12-120 sec. For the best revenue set the refresh rate as client gave.